# Instruct Scrapy to not automatically add `Content-Length` header if already exists

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a situation where a website fingerprints based off header order and casing.

I've been able to specify header order with correct case by:

```py
import json
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request


from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers as TwistedHeaders

class Test(Spider):
    name = 'test'
    custom_settings = {
        'DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS': {
            'aA': 'a',
            'Bb': 'b',
            'CC': 'c',
            'Content-Length': '14',
            'dD': 'd',
        },
    }
    
    # Preserve casing of headers
    TwistedHeaders._caseMappings[b'aa'] = b'aA'
    TwistedHeaders._caseMappings[b'bb'] = b'Bb'
    TwistedHeaders._caseMappings[b'cc'] = b'CC'
    TwistedHeaders._caseMappings[b'dd'] = b'dD'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(
            'https://httpbin.org/post',
            body=json.dumps({'foo': 'bar'}),
            method='POST',
            # Sniff with Fiddler
            # meta={'proxy': 'https://127.0.0.1:8866'}
        )
    
    def parse(self, response): pass
```

I notice in Fiddler that when I run the spider another `Content-Length` is present at the start of the request headers:

[image: Fiddler inspection of request]

I've tried to find where in Scrapy/Twisted this is being set, but as I am pretty new it is a lot to read through. As a result, I am having a hard time understanding why this is happening.

Is there anyway to instruct `Content-Length` to not be added automatically if it's already present? Or, if it is automatically added, for `Content-Length` to respect header order?

**I know that if I remove `Content-Length`, the request works; however, it is still unordered (`Content-Length` occurs as the first key in the headers). For my use case, I think `Content-Length` must occur in the right spot. For the case of this example, that's between `CC` and `dD`.**

I would appreciate any steps in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: The RFC Standard for http headers specifies that the sequence ordering is insignificant and that they are case insensitive, which means that the server you are communicating with would have to be customized to reject RFC standards.  Which is unusual for a public facing http server.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you very much for your response. I know section 3.2.2 of RFC states header order is insignificant for HTTP/1.1 protocol. However, I have empirical evidence that the website I am trying to scrape uses the order of headers as a form of browser fingerprinting. The last piece of the puzzle for me is this `Content-Length` header placement. May I ask, is there any way to customize that? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sort (alphabetically) and make case sensitive scrapy headers (including Content-Length) by:

1. ORDER: Creating a custom downloader which sets headers as sorted alphabetically
2. CASE SENSITIVE: Modifying `_caseMappings` of internal Twisted `Headers` class to allow case sensitive headers
3. Two "Content-Length" headers: modify Twisted `web/_newClient.py` `_writeToBodyProducerContentLength` method (found [here](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/src/twisted/web/_newclient.py#L779C1-L790C10)) to go from

```
def _writeToBodyProducerContentLength(self, transport):
-    self._writeHeaders(
-         transport,
-         networkString("Content-Length: %d\r\n" % (self.bodyProducer.length,)),
-     )
+    self._writeHeaders(transport, None)
```

My github repository code can be found [here](https://github.com/lay-on-rock/scrapy-case-sensitive-headers/tree/main)